# problema con tecla Enter en Label

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo este formulario(Botones y Label) el cual funciona correctamente con las teclas del formulario si damos click en cada boton si funciona aparecen del 0 al 9,  pero con los numeros del teclado hay un problema, el formulario lo muestro en forma modal *frm.ShowDialog();* y a nivel formulario cambie la propiedad KeyPreview para capturar los eventos del teclado pero cuando recien abro el formulario y como primer paso pulso la Tecla Enter me aparece el numero 1 en el label y no entiendo porque.
Si abro el formulario y pulso las Teclas del 0 al 9 y a final pulso la Tecla Enter si entra al evento keyDown entonces no entiendo bien que pasa??
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me sorprende que tengas esa reputación y no sepas escribir una pregunta de forma correcta, solo pones una imagen y tu explicación y se necesita código para poder apoyar

Comment: Quien tiene el foco cuando entras?

Comment: @gbianchi en el label desde que se inicializa el formulario

Comment: mmmm dudoso que lo tenga el label.. seguro no lo tiene el 1??? un label no suele tener el foco....

Comment: Lo tengo declarado asi label.focus() y si como lo comentas el foco pasa por defecto al boton 1

Comment: Lo que te esta pasando es justamente lo que tiene que pasar.. cuando apretas enter, el control que tiene el foco ejecuta su enter primero.. y por eso muestra el uno.. el foco no deberia estar ahi... pero un label, no puede tener el foco.. no es un control "foqueable"

Comment: Ya gracias, cambie el TabIndex del boton 1 al Tabindex del boton OK y listo.